# How to add a wider space between the dots and the numbers of a toc?

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to add a wider space between the dots of my toc and the roman numbers which are my page numbers. If not, the numbers cover the dots. But when I add some your suggestions (listof=flat), it does not work. Where did I make a mistake ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside=semi,headings=small,chapterprefix=true,listof=flat]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
        \addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\small}%changed to small caps in headers
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

        \addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

        \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

        \usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
        \usepackage{marginnote}
        %\reversemarginpar

         \begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \appendix \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} 

    \tableofcontents
    \part*{Annexes}

    \chapter{Entretiens}
    \section{Premier entretien}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \section{Deuxième entretien}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \section{Troisième entretien}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \section{Quatrième entretien}
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Since you use a KOMA class, you could use `listof=flat` as option. This should recalculate the space (needs two or more runs).

Comment: Excuse-me, but it does not work. Could you tell me, please, where I have to insert that piece of code?

Comment: As stated it is a class option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you add the following instructions to the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3.5em}
\makeatother
```

This works with or without the `tocloft` package being loaded. In fact, this works with all LaTeX document classes that don't radically modify the workings of `\@pnumwidth`.

In case you're curious: In the `scrbook` document class, the default value of `\@pnumwidth` is 1.55em. The command shown above adds (almost) 2em to this parameter.